# Is all Linear Programming (LP) problems solvable in Polynomial time?

Tags: linear-programming, computational-complexity

My question is; is all LP problems solvable in polynomial time?

I see an LP problem defined as follows,

> maximize  $~~c^Tx$
>
> subject to
>
> $~~~~~~~~~~Ax \leq b \\
>  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~x \geq 0$

where $A \in R^{m \times n}$.

I did some google search. I see simplex method is non-polynomial time algorithm, and interior point method takes $O((m+n)^{1.5}nL)$  arithmetic operations, where $L$ is a complicated quantity, roughly the log of the largest absolute value of the determinant of any square submatrix of A (more information [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143570/for-interior-point-methods-of-linear-programming-what-is-the-l-in-the-computa)).

Comment: Yes: pure linear programming problems are solvable in polynomial time. This no longer holds when variables become discrete and/or non linear equations come in the game.

Comment: The interior point method ($O( (m+n)^{1.5} n L) $) you pointed out is due to Vaidya FOCS 89. It has been improved to ($O(n^{\omega} L)$) [Cohen, Lee, Song STOC 19] https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07896